# When specifying -javaagent, is it possible to have a jarpath containing = (equal) in it?

Tags: java, command-line, maven-surefire-plugin, javaagents

## Question

Is it possible to use a jarpath containing an equal sign when specifying an agentlib ? For example, using some kind of escaping ?

Note: the syntax to specify the java agent is `-javaagent:jarpath[=options]` (see [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html)).

## Context

I have a Continuous Integration setup where paths contains an = (equal) sign.
And I have problems running the maven surefire plugin which fails at startup because the agent jar is not found.
I dig a bit and found that 
And our command line looks like `/<path-to-jre>/bin/java -javaagent:/<path-to-jenkins-workspace>/myProject=myJobName/.repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/<path-to-jenkins-workspace>/myProject=myJobName/target/jacoco.exec,append=true <other arguments to java dropped>`.
I made this command work by renaming the project to `myProject+myJobName`, thus I'm sure that the problem lies with the use of equal.

Note that the above command line is directly generated by maven-surefire-plugin, thus I don't have many options to alter it.

Comment: Here's the link to the OpenJDK javaagent argument parsing code: https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/28cf61ba0955833f75cf7ba2b80cf83c557300d5/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/InvocationAdapter.c#L66 (it doesn't look like to support escaping).

Answer (score 1):

According to Sylvain's comment, this is not possible with OpenJDK 9.

This is probably the same with earlier JDK and the one from Oracle